# How to determine $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(X_1+\cdot\cdot\cdot+X_n \leq n)$?

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution

Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of iid Poisson-distributed random variables with parameter $\lambda >0$. How can I calculate 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}P(X_1+\cdot\cdot\cdot+X_n \leq n)?$$

Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: No joint law (or correlation) assumed?

Comment: @SangchulLee The OP says iid.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I must have had too much pints at the pub. What a shame :(

Comment: When is this due?

Comment: Monday I think!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is
$$P\left(\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}n\le1\right).$$
If $\lambda=1$ the limit is $\frac12$ by the Central Limit Theorem.
Otherwise $\frac1n(X_1+\cdots+X_n)$ has mean $\lambda$ and variance
$\lambda/n$. This variance tends to zero, so the limit is $1$ for $\lambda<1$ and $0$ for $\lambda>1$. You can use Chebyshev's inequality to
prove this.

Comment: Can you explain me one step? How do we get a limit of $0.5$ for $\lambda = 1$ for example?